# My CASE statement is not returning what I need

Tags: sql

I have a table where by we have extra date columns for operatives to use to define the end of a tenancy but the case statement I am trying to run is not returning the date I require.

My table below:

```
extra_date_08 | extra_date_07  | extra_date_06 | extra_date_05 | Tency_st_dt
--------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
NULL          | NULL           | NULL          | NULL          | 2013-11-30
NULL          | NULL           | NULL          | 2023-04-29    | 2013-04-27
NULL          | NULL           | NULL          | 2023-04-10    | 2013-04-09
```

What I need is for the result to return the End date in order of the case, if null move onto the next **when** part until it runs out else it should define the end date as the else clause:

```
End Date   | 
------------
2018-11-30 | 
2023-04-29 | 
2023-04-10 |



SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN h.extra_date_08 <> NULL 
            THEN h.extra_date_08
        WHEN h.extra_date_07 <> NULL 
            THEN h.extra_date_07
        WHEN h.extra_date_06 <> NULL 
           THEN h.extra_date_06
        WHEN h.extra_date_05 <> NULL 
           THEN h.extra_date_05
        ELSE DATEADD(yyyy,5,CAST(A.tency_st_dt AS DATE)) 
    END 'End Date',
```

Comment: The other answers are correct. Just for some more info, the reason your query doesn't work is that most DBMS support three valued logic - {True, False, and Unknown}. Since NULL represents the absence of data, the values are Unknown rather than True or False. For example, if I have no idea what my age is, it's NULL. So the the statement "MyAge <> 30" isn't True or False. I might be 30, I might not. That's why you need the IS NULL operator.

Comment: @Error_2646, that's actually the answer to the question. The others are just corrected code. If you posted that, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Case _expression_ - since it returns a value. (A case statement has no return value, it's just conditional execution of code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `is not null` instead `<>`

```
SELECT  
CASE 
    WHEN h.extra_date_08 is not NULL 
        THEN h.extra_date_08
    WHEN h.extra_date_07 is not NULL 
        THEN h.extra_date_07
    WHEN h.extra_date_06 is not NULL 
        THEN h.extra_date_06
    WHEN h.extra_date_05 is not NULL 
        THEN h.extra_date_05
            ELSE DATEADD(yyyy,5,CAST(A.tency_st_dt AS DATE)) 
END 'End Date',
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(h.extra_date_08, h.extra_date_07, h.extra_date_06, h.extra_date_05,
                DATEADD(year, 5, CAST(A.tency_st_dt AS DATE))
               ) as EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The special value NULL represents an *unknown* value, hence you can't directly compare any actual value with it. Since NULL means unknown, any comparison with it will always evaluate to false:

```
@your_var = NULL // => False
@your_var <> NULL // => False
```

Regardless of the value of **@your_var**.

That is why your **CASE** expression always reaches the **ELSE** part.

As pointed out by @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, to check for NULL, you should use the **IS NULL** [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead. The **COALESCE** function suggested by @Gordon Linoff is actually just a [syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparing-coalesce-and-case) that gets transformed to the former expression underneath, but it definitely makes your code cleaner and nicer.

More on common scenarios similar to yours [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/).